# Autodiscovery using Mircosoft graph REST API

Tags: android, ios, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I am trying to implement auto discovery using Microsoft graph API which just uses my email address for my native mobile application. I have went through all the documents publicly available but didn't find any appropriate resource.

I am already using Microsoft Autodiscovery V1 to perform the autodiscovery using traditional approach but there is a limitation to this which required Basic authentication. I am targeting hybrid Exchange environment which have both cloud (Exchange online users) as well as on premise exchange users.

I have read that Microsoft has new Autodiscovery V2 which graph internally implements i just want to leverage that.

Can someone give me any example or point me to some tutorial which helps me understand.

Answer (score 0):

> I am already using Microsoft Autodiscovery V1 to perform the autodiscovery using traditional approach but there is a limitation to this which required Basic authentication

The V1 Autodiscover endpoint in Office365 will work fine with oAuth

The documentation for the v2 endpoint is very minimal but basically its an unauthenticated endpoint so any Get Request (even in a browser) will work fine. I guess the question is what are you trying to discover? if your working with Hybrid Modern Auth the the v2 endpoint is probably the best and easiest solution (it what Outlook uses).

```
https://outlook.office365.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.json/v1.0/bgates@microsoft.com?Protocol=EWS
```

Comment: I have read somewhere that i need to use graph which internally uses the Autodiscovery V2.
I am trying to disovery the mail address for the a particular user based on his email id. User can be either from cloud or on premise

Comment: The V2 looks easier as it is un authenticated and hence users dont need to pass their credentials to the app. Will it work for all the exchange user? ( 2016 CU3 or later ? )

Comment: https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.json?Email=xyz@test.com&Protocol=ActiveSync

Comment: Yes it should work for anyone with 2016 CU3 up, its not as rich in term of what it will return in comparison to the v1 endpoint as it more aimed at service discovery.